# Access data inside while loop

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm developing a web API with c# and SQL server. How can I do if I want to access the data ie:`objtoken.customer_id`  in while loop so that I can use it for further development.

**While loop**

```
while (_Reader.Read())
{
     Login_Model objtoken = new Login_Model();
     objtoken.user_id = _Reader["user_id"].ToString();
     objtoken.customer_id = _Reader["customer_id"].ToString();
    _return.Add(objtoken);
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear - you have `objtoken.customer_id`, you can use it.

Comment: how do i use it outside while loop @zmbq

Comment: You have many customer_ids. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: the first one @zmbq

Comment: Look at the `_return` collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the first customer_id, store it in a variable outside the loop:

```
string first_customer_id = null;

while (_Reader.Read())
{
   // your original loop content
   if (first_customer_id == null)
        first_customer_id = objtoken.customer_id;
}

// Here first_customer_id holds the first customer id, or is null if there were no customers
```